# What network errors, and verbage, should be alerted to the end user for a network app?

Tags: android, ios, networking, message

A mobile app I'm developing has network connectivity.  Yes, you're right, I know it's a crazy notion.

There are many possible errors that could occur with accessing remote resources, network and server, not to mention web application etc, and I've been trying to come up with an action plan on how to present a non-technical error information to the user, just saying something went wrong, but giving the user some hint as to what is going on, so they're not totally in the dark.

Does anyone have any general guidance (or specific would be great!) covering the entire domain of network errors, messages might be actually relevant to the user?  Granted, that's really open ended considering a user's technical comfortability.  But say, someone such as a grandparent that only uses technology infrequently, but is able to surf and email.

A supplementary question, but sort of fits within this, is:  are there any resources somewhere on the web, listing applicable network and server error messages?  (and any that have been localized and freely available??)  Web searches for "network error messages for dummies" and other related searches have yielded mostly useless results so far.

Comment: As a general rule, if the user can't do anything about it, then don't tell them.  Recover gracefully and continue.  If they can, then tell them what and link to where they need to go (e.g. turn WiFi on)

Comment: I go with Simon said, sometimes not being notified is a bliss.:)

Comment: To add more rationale, I have an app which displays some "latest data" from a server on a 5 minute schedule.  If Wifi and/or mobile data is on, and I can't get the data, there is nothing the user can do about it (ok, perhaps they walk into range :)).  In this case, at the top of the data display, I show the last retrieved time stamp.  If it's more than 5 minutes old, because it's adapter didn't feed it new data, I change the text to red, enlarge it a little and add a "click here to refresh".  99% of users are smart enough to manage their own connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check exceptions listed in the following links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/package-summary.html

I personally notify users when exceptions such as ConnectTimeoutException and SocketTimeoutException occur.